# UI UX best practice in changing applications app bar color?

Tags: navigation, color-scheme, branding

Hi I am designing an app for Android and IOS both will have appbars. I have a branding color of blue which is used in the app bars in the all of my activities. I am thinking of changing the app bar color for different modules inside the app.

Example

1. Main screen app bar is brand color of blue
2. when they go to profile all the app bar inside the profile modules are grey
3. When they go to buy new stuff all the app bar are colored white

Is it bad practice to do this? Will this confuse my users?

My goal is to make them aware through the app bar color that they have navigated to a totally different module of my app. (profile -> store) and (store -> reviews) etc.
Is this a good UI UX practice?

Comment: To discover best practices and industry standards, we usually do a competitive audit, looking at competitors' (and non-competitors') sites to see how they do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s not an issue as long as you have a great reason to make sense for that color changing. A good reason might be context, classification, organization...

Check out how Vine does when exploring throughout all categories. Each one is differentiated by one specific color used for hyperlinks, and nav bar.

When you do so, make sure the context is understood right and if the case is just to avoid using the same blue, maybe try out the same Hue but different saturation (+whiter or darker).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is more of a UI issue. Fonts and UI kits are just as important as colours. If you have created successful wireframe using just one colour then the UX should continue to be successful regardless of colour choice. Fonts and icons can still provide enough continuity to ensure a comfortable user enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how well you create your UI. If your design doesn't match then Changing App bar every time, feels very unnatural and users will find very difficulty in remembering your app UI.

Comment: So as long as the UI is consistent and intuitive there is no best practice rule being broken by changing colors of the app bar?